# I am trying to make a new dataframe from an existing dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
MATERIAL  Prod_Date  Prod_Qty        Status
0     107LPY04 2022-12-01         0           Yes
1     051DPY03 2022-12-01         4  Unavailable 
2     040LPY72 2022-12-01         0           Yes
3     025LPY61 2022-12-01         0           Yes
4     034LPY05 2022-12-01         0           Yes
```

The above table is my data. It is a 6251 rows data.

I want to make a new dataframe in which I will get only rows with status "Unavailable".

I used the command

```
df2 = (df[df.Status == "Unavailable"])
df2
```

But I get an empty dataframe.
There are total 6 Unavailable in Status Column. Hence I should get 6 rows as my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove trailing spaces:

```
df[df.Status.str.strip() == "Unavailable"]
```

Answer (score 0):

df_new = df[df["Status"] == "Unavalible"]